# curl command line , delay when closing

Tags: http, curl

Using the following curl command line

```
curl -i -L --silent -k "https://news.ycombinator.com" --no-keepalive -H 'Connection: close" --user-agent "NokiaN73-1/4.0736.3.2.1 Series60/3.0 Profile/MIDP-2.0 Configuration/CLDC-1.1" --cookie "cookie.news.ycombinator.com.txt" --cookie-jar "cookie.news.ycombinator.com.txt"
```

Everything works fine, however there is a delay between it receiving the last line of
the html ( the html close tag ), and curl successfully exiting..

There obviously is some delay, waiting for the connection to close,, but it's not needed, 
the file had been transferred completely and successfully..

How do I reduce or eliminate this delay

Comment: Seems like this is probably a server issue, it's not closing the connection quickly.

Comment: No it's not, because connecting to the same url using firefox, it closes immediately.

Comment: The cache of firefox can change something, maybe !?

Comment: I'm looking for a curl command line option to set the time_wait

Comment: I'm afraid that's on server side, not client side...

Comment: of course, yes your correct